# Syntax to fill linq array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am populating a "page" with a dynamic number of questions, (optional) options and user answers. During debugging I can see my fields filled out, but no matter what I have tried will the QuestionOptions populate as an array.

It is one question to many OR none options, there can be many responses to a question but only 1 per user ID.

Here is my Get Query;

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int page = 1) {
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var question = (from q in db.Questions
                    join qo in db.QuestionOptions on q.Id equals qo.QuestionId
                    join r in db.Responses on q.Id equals r.QuestionId
                    where q.PageNumber == page && r.UserId == userId
                    select new GetQuestionViewModel
                    {
//   DOESN'T WORK       QuestionOption1 = qo.QuestionOption1.ToList<QuestionOption>(),
//   DOESN'T WORK       QuestionOption = qo.QuestionOptions.ToList<QuestionOption1>(),
                        QuestionOptionRanking = qo.QuestionOptionRanking,
                        Id = q.Id,
                        Options = q.Options,
                        QuestionTypeId = q.QuestionTypeId,
                        Question1 = q.Question1,
                        QuestionRanking = q.QuestionRanking,
                        Answer = r.Answer
                     }).ToList();
    return View(question);
}
```

And this is my ViewModel;

```
public class GetQuestionViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Options { get; set; }
    public string QuestionOption1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionOptionRanking { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionRanking { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

THe View accommodates to 4 question types;

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model IEnumerable<Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View question";
    Html.BeginForm("ViewQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" });
}
@foreach (var q in Model) { var qtype = q.QuestionTypeId;
<div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<h1>@q.Question1</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">  
@switch (qtype)
{
     case 1:
    // Textbox
        @Html.TextArea("Answer", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", col = "5" });
        break;

    case 2:
    //  Dropdown
    <select class="form-control" id="Answer" name="Answer">
        @foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
        {
            <option value="@item.QuestionOption1">@item.QuestionOption1</option>

        }
    </select>
    break;

case 3:
//    Checkbox
    <div class="checkbox">
        @foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />  @item.QuestionOption1<br />

        }
    </div>
    break;

case 4:
//      Radio buttons
    foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
    {
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />
            @item.QuestionOption1
        </label>
    </div>
    }
    break;     
}
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" value="@q.Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@User.Identity.GetUserId()" />
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="@q.PageNumber" />

}
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Answer" />
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: yes, but I am very new and may not be implementing it correctly..

Comment: "`During debugging I can see my fields filled out`", so your `question` list is not empty? Can you show your `View` code?

Comment: Alex, you should read about navigation properties (and navigation property collections) in EntityFramework. It will solve your problem

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `QuestionOptions`?

Comment: That is where I am struggling; in the select statement I have tried QuestionOptions.ToList() AND QuestionOption1.ToList(), QuestionOptions being the table and QuestionOption1 the value but I cannot build when I add either of these.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple; my query was all wrong! With the help of some friends I FINALLY got the syntax correct to perform the query the way I wanted; sorting questions to the correct page, in the right order with their various options. Below is the query that worked in the end;

```
            List<GetQuestionViewModel> quest = new List<GetQuestionViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in db.Questions.Where(q => q.PageNumber == page).OrderBy(q => q.QuestionRanking))
        {
            quest.Add(new GetQuestionViewModel()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                QuestionOptions = db.QuestionOptions
                .Where(k => k.QuestionId == item.Id)
                .ToList(),
               PageNumber = item.PageNumber,
                Question1 = item.Question1,
                QuestionRanking = item.QuestionRanking,
                QuestionTypeId = item.QuestionTypeId
            });
        }
        return View(quest);
```

Hope this helps someone else as new to fluent Linq as I am! Thanks for all your input. It was a big help.